# Vector Calculus with parametrization

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Let $S$ be the unit sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$. Denote by $\mathbf{n}=(0,0,1)$ to be the "*north-pole*". Let $(s,t,0)$ to be an arbitrary point in the $xy$-plane. Draw the line from $\mathbf n$ to $(s,t,0)$ and determine where it intersects the sphere $S$, i.e. determine $x,y,z$ coordinates in terms of $s$ and $t$.
> This will give you functions,$$x=x(s,t)\qquad y=y(s,t)\qquad z=z(s,t)$$These functions will parametrize the sphere $S$.
>
> This parametrization of the sphere parametrizes only the entire sphere, it only misses the point $\mathbf n$.
>
> What is the domain for the $s,t$ variables?

Please help me with the solution.

Comment: The line intersects the sphere at $(0,0,1)$ for sure. What about the other point? What have you tried?

Comment: One point of the line is (0,0,1) and the other point is (s, t, 0).

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Unless the line is parallel to $XY$ plane, it will intersect the sphere in two points (one of them is obviously $n$). So that should tell you the domain of $s ,t $ variables.

Equation of the line from $n (0, 0, 1)$ to arbitrary point in $XY$ plane $(s, t, 0)$ -

$(0, 0, 1) + a(s, t, -1)$

If the line intersects the sphere, the points on this line $(as, at, 1-a)$ will satisfy the equation of the sphere -

$a^2s^2 + a^2t^2+a^2+1-2a = 1 \implies a^2s^2+a^2t^2+a^2-2a = 0$ so $a = 0$ is an obvious solution which from the line of equation gives point $(0, 0, 1)$ (we knew this was obvious).

Now can you use this to find the other possible value of $a$ and then the other point of intersection? You will also notice that parametrization will cover all points on the sphere except point $n (0, 0, 1)$.